# Bot is repeating itself?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm building a discord bot from the ground up, and I'm hosting the bot solely on my computer. not on Heroku or any other service. When I type ;help in my discord test channel, the bot will repeat the response for one instance roughly 6-8 times. it'll dump 4 at once, then 3 more, and then one more after that in like 4 second intervals.

```
import json
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN =  # My token

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ";")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def readycheck(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Bot is ready cap'n!")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def groot(ctx):
    await ctx.send("I am GAY!")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong!")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def info(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Welcome to the Testbot0124 designed by loving people")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Are you sure you only have one instance running? Cause those message don't look like they would trigger each other. (To avoid having message trigger each other, I use `if message.author == client.user: return` in my `on_message` event hook. Surely you can use something similar with the command hooks?)

Comment: ok so upon further investigation, it's because I have 13 instances running. Now the question is, what can I add in the code to cause the program to terminate itself instead of creating duplicate instances?

Comment: Terminate itself when? You'd normally only want it to terminate on request (e.g. when you send SIGINT to the process), not by itself.

Comment: terminate may not be the right word. So when I run the ;help command in my discord text channel, it responds 13 times. A friend of mine says it's because I have 13 instances running, but I didn't open them, so how can I rewrite the code, or what can I add to it so that it doesn't do that when I rune the ;help command?

Comment: Re "*but I didn't open them*", That is not true. Files on your drive don't just execute themselves.

Comment: Your code already does what you want when you type `;help`.

Comment: @ikegami you're not wrong. I do have to open the file itself, but what I mean by I didn't open it is when I type ;help which is 1 instance, the bot replies 13 times with the information under ;help instead of just once so it spams the channel 13 times

Comment: No, each bot only replied once, which is exactly what you asked. You got 13 messages because you have 13 bots. Terminate the extras.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a solution to this in the event someone else comes across the same problem. Instead of using my text editor to run my script, I started using terminal by `cd /` into the path directory, and using `python3 main.py` to run my files. I no longer have multiple instances of the bot running at the same time.